# How to avoid negative values when using sparse matrices in python?

Tags: python, adjacency-matrix

i am writing the following code using Sparse matrices

```
def Transition_Matrix(adj,beta):
    Iden = sp.eye(adj.shape[0])
    adj = sp.coo_matrix(adj)
    rowsum = np.array(adj.sum(1))
    degree_mat_inv_sqrt = sp.diags(np.power(rowsum, -0.5).flatten()
    adj_normalized = adj.dot(degree_mat_inv_sqrt).tocoo()
    matrix_=Iden-(beta * adj_normalized)
    ****print(matrix_)**** this is the result
here beta=0.9


1.         -0.3        -0.28460499 ... -0.36742346  0.
   0.        ]
 [-0.225       1.         -0.28460499 ...  0.          0.
   0.        ]
 [-0.225      -0.3         1.         ...  0.         -0.25980762
   0.        ]
 ...
 [-0.225       0.          0.         ...  1.         -0.25980762
  -0.21828206]
 [ 0.          0.         -0.28460499 ... -0.36742346  1.
  -0.21828206]
 [ 0.          0.          0.         ... -0.36742346 -0.25980762
   1.        ]]


matrixinv=np.linalg.pinv(matrix_)
Transition=(1-beta)*matrixinv
return Transition
```

the input is the sparse matrix:`adj = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G)`

How to avoid this negative values? any help will be appreciated